# why there is a shift from parallel to serial bus in pcie?

Tags: pci-e, pci-bus

There is parallel bus for pci and serial bus for pcie. Why parallel  bus cannot be used  for pcie but are using serial bus? why there is shift to serial bus for pcie?

Answer (score 0):

Parallel bus is hard to be fast because of synchronizing signals per clock. *Parallel* signals must be sent synchronously. On the other hand, serial bus can send signals asynchronously, so is easy to be fast.

Comment: so that why pcie is using serial bus and not parallel bus?

Comment: To be able send signals asynchronously, it's unnecessary to synchronize other signals. Synchronizing is more difficult than people think. Than that, much faster clock frequency is better to send much data.